# Exhibiting A Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Exhibit a basis and calculate the dimension of the following subspace S of $\mathbb{P}_2$.
>
> $S=\{a+b(x+x^2) \mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$

$\mathbb{P}_n$ denotes the vector space with polynomials of degree $n$ or less.

My work:

$a+b(x+x^2)=a+bx+bx^2=1(a)+x(b)+x^2(b)$

So the corresponding matrix is:
$$
\left[\left.\begin{array}{c c} 0 & 1\\0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{array}\ \right\rvert\ \begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\\\end{array}\right]\rightarrow\left[\left.\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{array}\ \right\rvert\ \begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\end{array}\right]
$$

I'm not sure if I'm doing this question correctly.

A hint or a push in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A subspace is never a basis! Could you please go back and look up the definition of what a basis is? Indeed, I could write an answer but it is not going to be very helpful...

Comment: Maybe you want to say subset rather than basis.

Comment: It's a textbook question I didn't understand. I copied the question down word for word. If it helps, the answer given in the back of the book is $\{1,x+x^2\}$ with $dimS=2$.

Comment: No! Please review the definition of linear independence and basis.

Comment: If I recall correctly, a basis of $V$ spans $V$ and the vectors in the basis are linearly independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We parametrize the subset $S$, then $S=\{a(1+0x+0x^2) + b(0+x+x^2)|a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$. So a natural basis for $S$ can be $B=\left\langle {(1+0x+0x^2),(0+x+x^2)} \right\rangle=\left\langle {1,x+x^2} \right\rangle.$ We know that $dim(S)$ is the number of elements of any basis of $S$, so $dim(S)=2$. We now prove that $B$ is basis.

For span, given a $\vec{v} \in S$, then $\vec{v}=c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{2}x^2$, so $$c_{1} \vec{\beta_{1}}+c_{2}\vec{\beta_{2}}=c_{1}(1)+c_{2}(x+x^2)=c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{2}x^2=\vec{v}.$$

For independence,

$$ c\vec{\beta_{1}}+d\vec{\beta_{2}}=\vec{0} \\ c(1) + d(x+x^2)=0+0x+0x^2$$

because polynomials are equal if and only if their coeficients are equal, then $c=0$ and $d=0$. So the only linear relationship between $\vec{\beta_{1}}$ and $\vec{\beta_{2}}$ is the trivial. Therefore $B$ is basis.